# Python code output not displaying barplot visualisation

Tags: python, output, visualization, boxplot

I have created a barplot but by code is not displaying it. Can someone help?

Thanks

[image: BOX PLOT]

Comment: You have specified a bar chart, so change it to a boxplot.

Comment: try adding `%matplotlib inline` at the beginning of your file/notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), the return is an `AxesSubPlot` instance, while a `Figure` instance is needed for display. Easiest way to do what you want is assigning it to a matplotlib figure instance as follow:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = ...

fig = plt.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

graph = sns.barplot(data=df, ax=ax)
```

Now you can call `fig` anywhere and get the graph.

Comment: Thanks for this! How about for a pie?

Comment: I do not think seaborn supports those. You can use the [matplotlib pie chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) ([example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html)), or the pandas pie chart (`df.plot.pie()`, [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html)). Note that `df.plot.pie()` takes `ax` as keyword argument, similar to the answer above. As long as you call the Figure instance (`fig`) rather than the Axes instance, it will work as requested.